# VS2010 block highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fonts, highlighting

How to turn off block highlighting for visual studio 2010 ? It is annoying specially when you are using custom font and color settings.

Comment: Selection highlight?  Press Escape.

Comment: Ah! Sorry wrong question and wrong place. found the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out. What you need to do is to set your "collapsible region" to have the same background color of "editor". Set it through "Tools-> Options -> General -> Font":

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vseditor/thread/ffa9db52-11d4-4017-9859-166dd3231b1c